# Removing matching nodes in PHP XML DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

`$content_properties` has the result of an xpath query: `<td>`'s containing some simple text values. I want to delete every node which value equals "last viewed". So I tried this:

```
<?php
    foreach($content_properties as $node){
        if($node->nodeValue == "last viewed"){
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            echo "yep - ".$node->nodeValue."<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "nope - ".$node->nodeValue."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

But when I again echo all of $content_properties node values afterwards, nothing has been deleted.

- I'm not getting warnings or errors.
- I added the yep/nope echoes to check if the expression is actually matching the correct nodes. It is.
- I tried changing the values of the matching nodes, just to see if that does work. It does.

Why can't I remove the matching nodes? Do I have to do something else to make the removal 'stick'? Am I not targeting the correct node?

Comment: let me suggest a simplified version: modify your original `xpath`statement and let it select `<td>` AND 'last viewed', then delete all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing works fine, the nodes are removed from their parent - they're just not removed from the `DOMNodeList $content_properties`.

---

#### Example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>last viewed</td>
    <td>baz</td>
    <td>last viewed</td>
</tr>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$content_properties = $xpath->query('//td');

foreach($content_properties as $node){
    if($node->nodeValue == "last viewed"){
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}

foreach($content_properties as $node){
    if($node->nodeValue == "last viewed"){
        echo "yep - ".$node->nodeValue."\n";
    }
    else{
        echo "nope - ".$node->nodeValue."\n";
    }
}

echo "\n", $dom->saveXML(), "\n";

// Regen the DOMNodeList
$content_properties = $xpath->query('//td');

foreach($content_properties as $node){
    if($node->nodeValue == "last viewed"){
        echo "yep - ".$node->nodeValue."\n";
    }
    else{
        echo "nope - ".$node->nodeValue."\n";
    }
}
```

---

#### Output:

```
nope - foo
nope - bar
yep - last viewed
nope - baz
yep - last viewed

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>

    <td>baz</td>

</tr>

nope - foo
nope - bar
nope - baz
```

Comment: Your answer is amazing. Not only is it working now, you also helped me completely understand why and provided a full example. Thank you!

Comment: `$content_properties = $xpath->evaluate('//td[. = "last viewed"]');`

Answer (score 0):

This is the right approach:

```
<?php
    foreach($content_properties as $node){
        if($node->nodeValue == "last viewed"){
            $content_properties->parentNode->removeChild($node);
            echo "yep - ".$node->nodeValue."<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "nope - ".$node->nodeValue."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: With this I'm getting "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array"

Comment: I can't give you a useful var_dump or print_r, since it's a [DOMNodeList object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617574/1745271). It contains a short list of <td>'s with some plain text values. But you need to have it in a DOMNodeList object to replicate the result; not a regular array. I thought it would be possible to manipulate the DOM object directly, instead of converting it to a temporary array first and then back to the DOM object.

Comment: Maybe it's as easy as replace the line `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);` with the line `$content_properties->parentNode->removeChild($node);` or the line `$content_properties->parentNode->removeChild($content_properties);`.

Comment: Sadly not. What I tried seemed to be the correct way: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602207/php-cant-remove-node-from-domdocument), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958659/dom-removing-selected-child-nodes). But first going to the parent to remove the child seems very odd to me. Why can't I just directly reference the current node? I'm starting to suspect that I can't delete the node, because there is no parent in my query result. I'll keep looking. Cheers for trying to stick with me :)